# WebSocket vs HTTP

Tags: http, websocket, https

Наткнулся на такую статью: https://habr.com/ru/post/646401/

Небольшая цитата:

> Я предполагаю, что все читающие статью ознакомлены с концепцией того,
> что такое веб-сокеты и HTTP, а также чем отличаются между собой
> запросы по HTTP и соединение по WS, но на всякий случай уточню этот
> момент. Когда браузер обменивается данными с сервером с помощью
> обычных HTTP-запросов, то при каждом запросе браузер устанавливает
> соединение, получает данные с сервера **и потом разрывает соединение**.
> Дела обстоят немного по-другому с Websocket: **браузер единоразово
> устанавливает соединение с сервером, и по этому соединению можно
> передавать данные в обе стороны** от сервера к клиенту, и от клиента к
> серверу, без задержек на установку соединения.

> и потом разрывает соединение

Зачем писать такое в 2022 году ? Keep-Alive существует из покон веку еще в http 1.1, а в http 2.0 - он используется вообще по умолчанию. К чему такое сравнение ?

> браузер единоразово устанавливает соединение с сервером, и по этому
> соединению можно передавать данные в обе стороны

Как единоразовое установление соединение коррелируется с двунаправленностью связи ?

Или я чего то не понимаю ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Keep-Alive существует

Но не дает возможности отправлять сообщения асинхронно. Новый запрос браузер вставляет после завершения предыдущего.

И хоть браузер с вэб сервером соедененны, но бэкэнд запускается для каждого запроса отдельно. Вэбсокет позволяет держать соединение без разрыва логики бэкэнда - а значит локальные переменные не нужно сохранять в сессию или куки при каждом чихе.

> Как единоразовое установление соединение коррелируется с двунаправленностью связи ?

"по этому" и "поэтому" разные слова. Двунаправленный канал внутри соединения.

Answer (score 0):

мало того, по ws возможна отправка без ответа на сообщение, чего нельзя для http.
но для этого сервер должен иметь работающее приложение, а не ответчик на запросы http (как стандартный сервер на  php)